# replace codeigniter 's active record in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, activerecord

Is there an equivalent for Codeigniter's implementation of active record in NodeJS somewhere?

I am well aware of the basic mysql connector, however all the security/convenience features that a newbie such as myself relies on to not end up in catastrophe don't appear to be there - it looks like just talking raw SQL to the database driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Tower](https://github.com/tower/tower) project.It is a node based project with very minimal dependencies
Or you can also look at [MySQL ActiveRecord Adapter for Node.js](https://github.com/martintajur/node-mysql-activerecord)

Comment: On the face of it, the active record adapter was what I was after... I'm still unlikely to move away from using express on the server-side simply due to support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check [JugglingDB](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb) - cross-db ORM for nodejs